# Add hyperlink back to another sheet/cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have one workbook with about 4 sheets. There is a main sheet that gets populated from user input on the other sheets. That part works fine. The user enters values on a sheet and the target cell on the main is appended to with that value.

What I am trying to do now is to create a hyperlink from the main sheet back to the specific cell/sheet that populated the main. I am using hyperlinks.add but it gives me a syntax error. The line of code that is working is:

```
Sheets("MainPage").Range(MCol & MRow).value = sheets("MainPage").Range(MCol & MRow).value & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory").Range(iCol & iRow).value
```

How can I push the Inventory value to the main page as a hyperlink that returns to that cell in inventory when the user clicks on it?

Comment: `Cells(MRow, MCol)` - etc

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure I understand your comment. Is that part of a hyperlink statement?